# How to preset a radio button when they are instantiated?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a settings window for a game, I would like the user to be able to choose the background colour of the game window by using radio buttons. I need to be able to have a pre-selected button in case they don't go into the settings and select a colour (a default colour).

Comment: just use `radio_button.select()` where `radio_button` is your pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.select()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm#Tkinter.Radiobutton.select-method) method of Radiobutton.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()

rb1 = tk.Radiobutton(root, text="One", variable=v, value=1)
rb1.pack(anchor="w")
rb1.select()

root.mainloop()
```